# android how can i read file or directory from usb host and copy to other place

Tags: android, file, copy, usb

I need your help, I'm trying to read some directory and trying to copy it to another place.
Now I can connect to usb host and read the usb specifications but i can´t read the information on the usb to copy it.

this is my code

```
 if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if (device != null) {
                        //call method to set up device communication
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
                        int TIMEOUT = 0;
                        boolean forceClaim = true;
                         intf = device.getInterface(0);
                        UsbEndpoint endpoint = intf.getEndpoint(0);
                         connection = manager.openDevice(device);
                        connection.claimInterface(intf, forceClaim);
                        bytes=connection.getRawDescriptors();
                        Toast.makeText(context,"PERMISO CONCEDIDO",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ArrayList<String>directorios=new ArrayList<>();
                        directorios=ObtnerDirectorios("/storage/UsbDriveA");
                        String dir="";
                        for(int i=0; i<directorios.size();i++){
                            dir+=directorios.get(i)+"\n";
                        }
                        infotext.setText(dir);


                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"PERMISO DENEGADO",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

I read the google documentation and I think t have to use a bulktransfer and control transfer but I'm not sure.
Could you help me?

Thanks